# Travis: how to execute stage on specific commit message

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, commit

I would like to execute a travis stage only on specific commit message (finally on a text tag in a commit message, but let's simplify for now).
Travis allows conditional execution using `if` statement (and I prefer to use that, because of the structure of my travis file). Travis documentation mentions 2 variables that could be used to get commit message:
`commit_message` and `TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE`
I tried using both of them. In these cases:

```
- stage: Deploy
  if: commit_message = "deploy" AND type = push


- stage: Deploy
  if: $TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE = "deploy" AND type = push
```

the stage is executed always, no matter what is the content of the commit message.

In that case:

```
- stage: Deploy
  if: env(TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE) = "deploy" AND type = push
```

The stage is never executed, no matter what is the content of the commit message.

I also tried adding `conditions: v1` in the root of the .travis file, but with no effect.
It seems like comparison operator is not working as expected (especially in first two cases - how can it always be true if strings are not equal??).